# Netbeans issues Error code -1, SQL state 42Z93 when trying to execute a CREATE TABLE sql command

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, derby, javadb

This is what I try to execute:

```
CREATE TABLE "order" (
    "o_id" INTEGER not null primary key,
    "c_id" INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (o_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES customer(c_id)
);
```

Get this error when I execute the above SQL command:

> Error code -1, SQL state 42Z93: Constraints 'SQL120326130633321' and
>   'SQL120326130633320' have the same set of columns, which is not
>   allowed.

Before the above SQL command I executed this:

```
CREATE TABLE "customer" (
    "c_id" INTEGER not null primary key,
    "c_first" VARCHAR(30),
    "c_last" VARCHAR(30)
);
```

**EDIT(solution):**

I think I fixed it.

First, I had to remove the `PRIMARY KEY(o_id)` since it basically repeated what I have typed on line 2 of SQL command `o_id INTEGER not null primary key` so it complained I tried to create primary key for the same column twice.

Second, after that was fixed another error surfaced telling me that `CUSTOMER` table couldn't be found. Perhaps the problem was that I used the commas("...") around the table name 'customer' when `CREATE TABLE` was trying to execute.

I deleted 'customer' table and recreated it without using any quotations in the SQL command.

Afterwards I executed the 'CREATE TABLE' for 'orders' and it worked.

Strange difference is that when I used the quotations around the customer table name in SQL, at first, its name appeared all lower case in the Databases Explorer of Netbeans. But when I omitted the quotes the table names became all uppercase - even thier column names.

Comment: Did customer get executed successfully?

Comment: Yeah. I now have a customer table in my database.

Comment: You can and should post your solution as an answer to this question(which you can accept later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the primary key constraint twice. You only need it once, in one place or the other depending on DB vendor.

Comment: I removed the PRIMARY KEY(o_id) part, because I assume that was the problem since I already declared o_id as primary on line 2. But now I get this error: `Error code -1, SQL state X0Y46: Constraint 'SQL120326133325951' is invalid: referenced table CUSTOMER does not exist.` But the customer tables does exist and I see it right here with all the columns.

Comment: you should update your post to reflect your current code and thus the current problem. You'll get better responses that way. Take a look at w3schools sql lessons on foreign key constraints.